# Bootstrap Datepicker next year button dissappears when showing only months and setting an endDate

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I gave the Datepicker a StartDate and an EndDate but user can't go to last year that in the interval.

I configured the Bootstrap Datepicker for showing and selecting only year and month. Here is my code:

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                format: "mm/yyyy",
                startView: "months", 
                minViewMode: "months",
                multidate: true,
                multidateSeparator: ", ",
                startDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                endDate: new Date(),
});
```

It works but when user clicks to see previous year, next year button dissappears as in below images.

[image: First Initialization]
[image: Previouse Month]

Comment: it's a problem in the css.  could you inspect the hidden text in the developer console and see what line of css is causing the problem?

Comment: @WEBjuju thank you for your opinion. Js file caused the problem. When I checked the up to date version of Bootstrap Datepicker file I noticed that the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very detailed examination I noticed the problem occurs in "updateNavArrows" function in bootstrap-datepicker javascript file. Calculations for month view was wrong. I noticed that I am using older version of this file and when I upgraded it to a newer version, problem dissappeared.